# Facebook: Application Menu points to Connect URL for Facebook application

Tags: facebook

I have an IFrame app, and I would like to use some Connect features using javascript.

But when I set the Connect URL in the application settings, it then causes two problems.

1) The link for the app in the Application Menu now points to:
    http://mydomain.com/myapp/
instead of:
    http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/

2) The request opens in a new window (instead of the same window, as other apps do)

Is there any way to fix that? I'd like my application continue to use http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/  even after setting the Connect URL

Many thanks for reading

Comment: I have found a solution for ue problem and once i discovered it , i returned back to ur question to answer it so look at my answer i have modified it.
hope this will help u and waitting ur comments if so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

after 3 months you guys probably found out the answer. But as many others might have the same problem, as I did, the correct configuration seems to be the next one:

1. In the Canvas Callback URL you insert your server´s URL (where the work really happens)
2. In the Bookmark URL you insert something like this: http: slash slash apps dot facebook dot com slash YOURCANVASNAME slash - i.e., if your canvas name is acmeenterprises, so your Bookmark URL has to be http: slash slash apps dot facebook dot com slash acmeenterprises slash
3. The Connect URL is the main URL of your host - normally.

Hope it helps!

Alexandre.

Comment: i think the fact is that... don't mix the facebook connect function with any of the existing app. Facebook app is Facebook app, use canvas callback url but don't input connect url.  FBConnect is for apps that not inside Facebook, so open a new app for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact problem - on some pages (like profile settings) it shows iframe URL, and on some - correct apps.facebook... URL.
There is similar topic on fb forum. Seems like general bug
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=33364